# ajax call won't execute synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, performance

I have built a weather website that calls the flickr API 1st, then calls the yahoo API for the weather. The problem is that the data from the ajax call - from the yahoo API is not here in time for the page to load its content.

Some of the things I have used to try and slow the ajax call down:

- `setTimeout`
- wrapping the entire function that `$.ajax(success: )` calls into another function, wrapping it in `setTimeout`
- taking the callback function out of `$.ajax(success: )`, and putting into the `$.ajax(complete: )` param
- taking the `data` object  that `$.ajax(success: )` passes in, and copying that to another var, then going outside of ajax call and putting the function that handles the data inside of `$.ajaxComplete()`, passing new object `var`

There are more ways that I have tried to go about this, but I have been at it for 3 days and cannot find a solution. Can someone please help me here

Here is a link to the project

[My Weather App On codeine.io](http://codepen.io/NorrisWW/pen/XdoGdo?editors=0110)

```
function RunCALL(url)
    {
      var comeBack = $.ajax({
      url: url,
      async: false,
      dataType:"jsonp",
      crossDomain: true,
      method: 'POST',
      statusCode: {
      404: function() {console.log("-4-4-4-4 WE GOT 404!");},
      200: function() {console.log("-2-2-2-2 WE GOT 200!");}},
      success: function(data){ 
      weatherAndFlickrReport(data);},                                                                                                                     
      error: function(e) {console.log(e);}         
     });  
    }
```

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: Asynchronicity is kind of the point of Ajax (The A stands for "Asynchronous"). If you put all the logic in the success handler, and no part of the page depends on the Ajax coming back right away, you will be ok.

Comment: Please show your code. We can't troubleshoot asynchronous problems without it

Comment: Making certain parts of a text bold should indicate that those parts are important. it is a bit useless to write the whole question with bold text. It neither makes it more important nor does it increases the probability that it will be answered.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `"false"` – `async: false,`. The option expects a boolean value, rather than a string.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I originally wrote `false`, that was my hopeless attempt to try and get a different result

Comment: JSONP requests cannot be performed synchronously. This is [explained in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the `async` option – "*Cross-domain requests and `dataType: "jsonp"` requests do not support synchronous operation.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using jQuery? If so, you have to chain your callbacks. Which, at a high level, would looks something like:

```
//You might want to use .get or .getJSON, it's up to what response you're expecting...
$.getJSON('https://example.com/api/flickr', function(response) {
  //This your callback. The URL would end up being https://example.com/api/yahoo/?criteria=lalalalala
  $.getJSON('https://example.com/api/yahoo/', { criteria: response.propertyYouWant}, function(yahooResponse) {
    //Do something with your response here.
    });
});
```

Edit: I have updated your snippet with a working solution (based on the above AJAX requests) which now shows both your JSON objects ready for consuming. [Looky here.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPgjpb?editors=0110)

Comment: yes I am using jQuery. However, the same $.ajax is being executed for the flickr and yahoo call. I am not using flickr data to retrieve yahoo data. Its two separate calls, just the same function to handle two diff requests. I have flags set to make sure they don't over-run each other. Why can't I do this in $.ajax()? how can I fully receive the data from the call first, then send it to the function of choice? I don't want to handle the data in the same function that I have made the call in.

Comment: That's the whole nature of asynchronous patterns, and the need for callbacks. You can never guarantee that you'll be able to get data separately from those two API calls (unless we start talking about yields and promises and generators and other ES6 patterns, but that's a whole different topic). Whether you use it with .ajax or .getJSON, you'll have to implement a callback for one API call to chain to the next one, and then that callback will take care of whatever needs to happen next. And your callback CAN be a function... you don't need to have it be an inline AJAX request per se...

Comment: I am having trouble posting more code to show my implementation

Comment: If you're worried about the page loading too early, wrap everything in `$(document).ready(function() { //Your stuff goes here }); and you can guarantee proper execution.

Comment: Its the script that is not loading before the page. I have done what you said on both accounts and it has not worked. It would really help you you could just take a quick look, load the page and see what I am talking about. The link is included in the original post.

Comment: @rizers : I took a look at your script and did a fair amount of refactoring. For starters, you were calling `new whateverFunction()` a good bit, which in the context of what you were trying to do, was not the cleanest of solutions. I was able to set up some callbacks that you can see now allow you to make full use of both API responses. To be honest, I couldn't quite figure out what you were trying to accomplish from a UI perspective, so I just kept the scope of the solution to ensuring you'd be able to get the objects and use them. The console.log(s) show it. Let me know if that works!